# Multiple levels of page id migraton

Tags: graph, facebook-page

The graph api returns an error message indicating that the page id has been migrated:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#21) Page ID 147467101963429 was migrated to page ID 279123585523500.  Please update your API calls to the new ID", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 21
  }
}

However, following the page id 279123585523500 also returns a migrated page which redirects to 550149031667767.

As a developer, what are the best practices for dealing with pageid migrations? Is there a table that Facebook exposes that provides an easy lookup for such migrations?

Comment: Where are you getting the migrated page IDs from? Anywhere in the API that i can think of should be returning only the current page ID